Wavefunction with determinate momentum
In page 100 Griffiths' Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, Griffiths states that the eigenvector of $\hat{p}$ in the position basis is $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi\hbar}}e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}$ and states that

...there is no such thing as a particle with a determinate angular momentum... none of the the eigenfunctions of $\hat{p}$ lives in Hilbert Space...

I have the following two questions:

If we were to measure the momentum of a particle to be $p$, what would its wave function in the position basis $\Psi(x,t)$  be? (Remember, $\Psi(x,t)$ is normalizable!)
I suspect that I know the answer to the above question (correct me if I am wrong): You can't measure a particle's momentum exactly. There is always some uncertainty and the measured momentum has to lie in some range $[p-\Delta p,p+\Delta p], \Delta p >0$. Therefore after observing the particle's momentum, the wavefunction collapses to a function which is similar to $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi\hbar}}e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}$, yet normalizable.
Textbooks seem to be ignorant of the fact that a particles cannot have determinate momentum and state that momentum is quantised in some cases. For example in page 273 of Schroeter's Introduction to Thermal Physics, in the case of the infinte square well of length $L$, he writes


... the allowed wavelengths and momenta are $\lambda_n=\frac{2L}{n}, p_n=\frac{h}{\lambda_n}=\frac{hn}{2L}$...

Isn't this objectively wrong physics?

Your Q2 is correct. You are supposed to work with wavepackets. The result is that all the handwavy arguments we do, pretending that momentum "eigenfunctions" are admissible, end up giving the correct results.
Your Q3 is just you misunderstanding things. Those wavefunctions are in the infinite square well. They are, by definition, finite in extent. The wavelengths there are not free to be any continuous variable, but are instead discretised. There is no disagreement between the notion in Q1 and in Q3.
